# How to ignore echo off and get the commands execution log

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I have a read-only script with the first line turning off the echoing. For example `script.bat` with content:

```
@echo off
REM bunch of logic goes here
@echo on
```

Is it possible to trick it somehow and get all the commands echoed/printed anyways?
I can do call anything before/after the script invocation, just cannot change the script code itself. I imagine it would be something like this:

```
REM what can I do here?
call script.bat
REM execution log printed?
```

Comment: `@echo off` just disables echoing the command being executed, not the output of the command. The `bla bla` will be visible with or without `@echo off`

Comment: @MCND Sorry, the example was oversimplified. Edited the question to reflect the actual intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way of doing it, being the batch file read-only is to copy the file, remove the `@echo off` and run the copied file.

If this is not possible, you can try with the [buffer overflow](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6438) discovered by Jeb. Create a batch file with the following content

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
```

(a bit more than 256 opening parenthesis), open a `cmd` instance and execute it. Then, from the same `cmd` instance, call the `script.bat`. *Maybe* you could see the commands executed if the buffer overflow does not interfere.

At this moment I don't remember another way.

***note***: Just for completion, what you ask is technically possible, but not directly solvable. Some time ago, to solve a question about batch file invocation, `goto` commands and labels I patched a copy of the `cmd.exe` process to elude any check on when to output the command being executed, but this process depends of the exact version of the `cmd` executable.

Comment: Beautiful! Buffer overflow works like a charm. I did the following: one script with 256 opening parenthesis, and the main script doing `call cmd-overflow.bat` and then `call script-to-debug.bat`, and all the details get printed.

Answer (score 2):

This lengthy command reads `sample.bat` line-by-line, and for each line that does not explicitly say `@echo off`, it executes it, effectively skipping `@echo off`.

```
@for /F "tokens=*" %a in (sample.bat) do  @if NOT "%a" == "@echo off" %a
```

It may not be perfect for complex bat files that have sneaky ways of turning off command-echoing, but it should work in most basic cases: